# Can asyncio subprocess be used with contextmanager?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-asyncio, contextmanager

In python (3.7+), I am trying to run a subprocess as a contextmanager while asychronously streaming potentially large amounts of stdout. The problem is that I can't seem to get the body of the contextmanager to run asynchronously with the stdout callback. I have tried to use threads, running the async function there, but then I could not figure out how to get the Process object back out into the contextmanager.

So the question: how can I yield the async Process object from a contextmanager in the main thread while it is running? That is, I'd like to yield the already-and-currently-running Process from open_subprocess() before it is finished running in the following code.

```py
import asyncio
import contextlib

async def read_stream(proc, stream, callback):
    while proc.returncode is None:
        data = await stream.readline()
        if data:
            callback(data.decode().rstrip())
        else:
            break

async def stream_subprocess(cmd, *args, stdout_callback=print):
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        cmd,
        *args,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    read = read_stream(proc, proc.stdout, stdout_callback)
    await asyncio.wait([read])
    return proc

@contextlib.contextmanager
def open_subprocess(cmd, *args, stdout_callback=print):
    proc_coroutine = stream_subprocess(
        cmd,
        *args,
        stdout_callback=stdout_callback)
    # The following blocks until proc has finished
    # I would like to yield proc while it is running
    proc = asyncio.run(proc_coroutine)
    yield proc
    proc.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time

    def stdout_callback(data):
        print('STDOUT:', data)

    with open_subprocess('ping', '-c', '4', 'localhost',
                         stdout_callback=stdout_callback) as proc:
        # The following code only runs after proc completes
        # but I would expect these print statements to
        # be interleaved with the output from the subprocess
        for i in range(2):
            print(f'RUNNING SUBPROCESS {proc.pid}...')
            time.sleep(1)

    print(f'RETURN CODE: {proc.returncode}')
```

Comment: You'll need asynccontextmanager https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.asynccontextmanager

Comment: @altunyurt That did look promising, but awaiting on the call to `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec()` blocks and prevents entry into the asynccontextmanager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asyncio provides parallel execution by virtue of suspending anything that looks like it might block. For this to work, all code must be inside callbacks or [coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) and refrain from calling blocking functions like `time.sleep()`. Other than that, your code has some other issues, such that `await asyncio.wait([x])` is equivalent to `await x`, which means that `open_subprocess` won't yield until all of stream reading is done.

The correct way to structure the code is to move the top-level code into an `async def` and use an async context manager. For example:

```
import asyncio
import contextlib

async def read_stream(proc, stream, callback):
    while proc.returncode is None:
        data = await stream.readline()
        if data:
            callback(data.decode().rstrip())
        else:
            break

@contextlib.asynccontextmanager
async def open_subprocess(cmd, *args, stdout_callback=print):
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        cmd, *args, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    asyncio.create_task(read_stream(proc, proc.stdout, stdout_callback))
    yield proc
    if proc.returncode is None:
        proc.terminate()
        await proc.wait()

async def main():
    def stdout_callback(data):
        print('STDOUT:', data)

    async with open_subprocess('ping', '-c', '4', 'localhost',
                               stdout_callback=stdout_callback) as proc:
        for i in range(2):
            print(f'RUNNING SUBPROCESS {proc.pid}...')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    print(f'RETURN CODE: {proc.returncode}')

asyncio.run(main())
```

If you insist on mixing sync and async code, you'll need to completely separate them by running the asyncio event loop in a separate thread. Then your main thread will not be able to directly access asyncio objects like `proc` because they are not thread-safe. You'll need to consistently use `call_soon_threadsafe` and `run_coroutine_threadsafe` to communicate with the event loop.

That approach is complex and requires inter-thread communication and fiddling with event loops, so it's not something I would recommend except as a learning exercise. Not to mention that if you're using another thread, you needn't bother with asyncio at all - you could directly issue sync calls in the other thread. But having said that, here goes a possible implementation:

```
import asyncio
import contextlib
import concurrent.futures
import threading

async def read_stream(proc, stream, callback):
    while proc.returncode is None:
        data = await stream.readline()
        if data:
            callback(data.decode().rstrip())
        else:
            break

async def stream_subprocess(cmd, *args, proc_data_future, stdout_callback=print):
    try:
        proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
            cmd, *args, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    except Exception as e:
        proc_data_future.set_exception(e)
        raise
    proc_data_future.set_result({'proc': proc, 'pid': proc.pid})
    await read_stream(proc, proc.stdout, stdout_callback)
    return proc

@contextlib.contextmanager
def open_subprocess(cmd, *args, stdout_callback=print):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    # needed to use asyncio.subprocess outside the main thread
    asyncio.get_child_watcher().attach_loop(loop)
    threading.Thread(target=loop.run_forever).start()
    proc_data_future = concurrent.futures.Future()
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(
        loop.create_task,
        stream_subprocess(cmd, *args,
                          proc_data_future=proc_data_future,
                          stdout_callback=stdout_callback))
    proc_data = proc_data_future.result()
    yield proc_data
    async def terminate(proc):
        if proc.returncode is None:
            proc.terminate()
            await proc.wait()
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(terminate(proc_data['proc']), loop).result()
    proc_data['returncode'] = proc_data['proc'].returncode
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.stop)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time

    def stdout_callback(data):
        print('STDOUT:', data)

    with open_subprocess('ping', '-c', '4', 'localhost',
                         stdout_callback=stdout_callback) as proc_data:
        for i in range(2):
            print(f'RUNNING SUBPROCESS {proc_data["pid"]}...')
            time.sleep(1)

    print(f'RETURN CODE: {proc_data["returncode"]}')
```

Comment: The key insight this answer provides is that there is no need to await on created tasks. I thought I had to explicitly await on all tasks that should be run within an event loop -- specifically, the task created from the `read_stream` coroutine. I'm still not sure why this is.

Comment: @Johann Your intuition is not entirely misplaced - it is indeed a good idea to ultimately await the spawned task, otherwise unhandled exceptions raised by tasks will get lost. But it's definitely true that the task doesn't need to be awaited right away - in this case, it might be a good idea to await the task created from `read_stream()` after the `yield`. See [this article](https://vorpus.org/blog/notes-on-structured-concurrency-or-go-statement-considered-harmful/) for a longer treatise on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

The way to go with [`@contextlib.asynccontextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.asynccontextmanager) and `Process.wait()` routine (waits for child process to terminate, sets and returns `returncode` attribute):

```
import asyncio
import contextlib

async def read_stream(proc, stream, callback):
    while proc.returncode is None:
        data = await stream.readline()
        if not data:
            break
        callback(data.decode().rstrip())


async def stream_subprocess(cmd, *args, stdout_callback=print):
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(cmd, *args,
                                                stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    await read_stream(proc, proc.stdout, stdout_callback)
    return proc


@contextlib.asynccontextmanager
async def open_subprocess(cmd, *args, stdout_callback=print):
    try:
        proc = await stream_subprocess(cmd, *args, stdout_callback=stdout_callback)
        yield proc
    finally:
        await proc.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time

    def stdout_callback(data):
        print('STDOUT:', data)


    async def main():
        async with open_subprocess('ping', '-c', '4', 'localhost',
                                   stdout_callback=stdout_callback) as proc:
            # The following code only runs after proc completes
            for i in range(2):
                print(f'RUNNING SUBPROCESS {proc.pid}...')
                time.sleep(1)

        print(f'RETURN CODE: {proc.returncode}')

    asyncio.run(main())
```

Sample running output:

```
STDOUT: PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
STDOUT: 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
STDOUT: 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.074 ms
STDOUT: 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
STDOUT: 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.067 ms
STDOUT: 
STDOUT: --- localhost ping statistics ---
STDOUT: 4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
STDOUT: round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.048/0.062/0.074/0.010 ms
RUNNING SUBPROCESS 35439...
RUNNING SUBPROCESS 35439...
RETURN CODE: 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I suppose I was unclear. I am expecting the "RUNNING SUBPROCESS" lines to be interleaved with the "STDOUT" lines. Here, the body of the context is not entered until after the process is finished.

Comment: @Johann, you didn't mention about "interleaving", you had not a asynccontextmanager - you have it now. To get a sophisticated interprocess communication you need to elaborate all the rules and present the expected output

Comment: I thought I was clear with the statement (comment in the code) "I would like to yield proc while it is running". In my example code and yours, the context yields only after the process has finished. Note that both of our examples give identical output. I will copy that comment out into the prose of the question.